# Converting empty types to strings from an XLS row

Tags: python, json, excel, list, types

Amateur hour: I have to use Python because Ruby's Roo gem is absurdly slow and libraries available to Node.js are unable to parse these particular XLSX files (corrupted on generation perhaps?)

Python's xlrd is fast and is able to parse the files, so I need to dump the contents of an XLSX file as JSON to another file.

The first few lines of the document contain a lot of empty cells and, via [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd), look like this:

```
[empty:u'', empty:u'', text:u'loan Depot Daily Leads', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'', empty:u'']
```

I was hoping to iterate through the list and dump JSON line-by-line to a file like so:

```
import xlrd
import json

book = xlrd.open_workbook("loan Depot Daily Leads.xlsx")
# print("The number of worksheets is {0}".format(book.nsheets))
# print("Worksheet name(s): {0}".format(book.sheet_names()))
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
# print("{0} {1} {2}".format(sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols))
# print("Cell D30 is {0}".format(sh.cell_value(rowx=29, colx=3)))
with open("dumped.json", "a+") as myfile:
  for rx in range(sh.nrows):
    row = sh.row(rx)
    print(row)
    print(json.dumps(row))
    myfile.write(json.dumps(row))
```

However, I get a type error: `TypeError: empty:u'' is not JSON serializable`.

Is there a way to cast the empty types as empty strings so I can use `json` without worry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
import xlrd
import json
import datetime

book = xlrd.open_workbook("loan Depot Daily Leads.xlsx")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

rows = []
for rx in range(sh.nrows):
  row = sh.row(rx)
  items = []
  for cx, cell in enumerate(row):
    if sh.cell_type(rx, cx) == xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE:
      # This turns xlrd.xldate's float representation into 
      # JSON-parseable string
      py_date = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(cell.value, book.datemode)
      items.append(str(py_date)) 
    elif cell.value == None:
      # NoneType will error out if you try to stringify it;
      # appending empty string instead
      items.append('')
    else:
      items.append(cell.value)
  rows.append(items)
with open("leads.txt", "a+") as leadsfile:
  leadsfile.write(json.dumps(rows))
```